# How to stick div element to another div whatever the width of the latter

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Here's my [jsfiddle's example](http://jsfiddle.net/96kPj/2/).

there are 2 kind of content :

1st:

```
<div>
    <div class="content">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="buttonContainer">
        <button>A</button>
    </div>  
</div>
```

2nd :

```
<div>
    <div class="buttonContainer">
        <button>A</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        content
    </div>   
</div>
```

I'm trying to have a div element stuck to another div whatever the width of the latter. I'm using jquery ui for the blind effect.

You can see in the exemple that I know how to do this with the blind effect from left to right, but from right to left I'm stuck.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this ?

**EDIT :**
Maybe my explanation was confusing but all the jsfiddle you gave me didn't work as expected. 
What I want is that the button moves accordingly to the width of the container. In case of A, it works. But in B, the button stays on its position but I want him to "follow" the container.

Comment: Because you are using `toggle` which resets the `display` to `block` when showing. So, your `table-cell` gets reset to `block`. Don't use toggle, do the animation separately.

Comment: @abhitalks So you mean that I should use hide/show with blind effect ?

Comment: No. These methods all reset the display to block. Use animation. Or set the display back to table-cell manually, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/96kPj/3/

Comment: I'll give it a try. By the way, I don't see any changes with your example.

Answer (score 0):

I tried on your fiddle and edit the css,it seems right:

```
#content1, #content2 {
    background-color: #dadada;
    border: 1px grey solid;
}
#container1,#container2 {
    display: table;
}
#content1, #content2, .buttonContainer {
    display: table-cell;
}
#B{display: table-cell;}
```

Hope that would be what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for your button should be next to the box of your content.

toggle makes it back to `display:block`. To avoid this you can provide css after toggle to make it back to `display:table-cell`.

I added it after toggle event. you can play it in fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/96kPj/5/